# Draw a Rect using GUI.DrawTexture on exactly gameobject's position Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rect, gameobject

I have to use the "GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect..." function to draw a rectangle on my screen(actually, it's a gradient GUI bar i got from https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19972, but deep inside it's just a rectangle). I want to do it right beside a gameobject i have on my screen.

The problem is: It seems like rectangle's coordinates are not the same as a gameobjects coordinates(i have searched online and i guess it's true). I have tried the function below to convert a gameobject's position to a rectangle's coordinates but still no luck:

```
 public Vector2 WorldToGuiPoint(Vector2 position)
     {
         var guiPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
         guiPosition.y = Screen.currentResolution.height - guiPosition.y;

         return guiPosition;
     }
```

My best strike was when i did this:

```
Vector3 gameObjectsPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject);
```

And then when i wanted to draw the rectangle i did:

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(gameObjectsPosition.x, Screen.height - gameObjectsPosition.y, Background.width * ScaleSize, Background.height * ScaleSize), Background);
```

But still, the Rect isn't on the exact gameObject's position. It's x is right but y don't and when i searched the internet, they said I only had to do the "Screen.height - gameObjectsPosition.y" when drawing the Rect. It didn't work for me, the y is still wrong.

What should i do to create a rectangle that's like, right beside a current gameobject on screen (like, if the gameobject's position is x = -401 and y = -80, i want it on y=-80 and x=-300)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Screen.height` instead of 
`Screen.currentResolution.height`

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class GuiPosition : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Vector2 WorldToGuiPoint(Vector3 GOposition)
    {
        var guiPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(GOposition);
        // Y axis coordinate in screen is reversed relative to world Y coordinate
        guiPosition.y = Screen.height - guiPosition.y;

        return guiPosition;
    }

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        var guiPosition = WorldToGuiPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        var rect = new Rect(guiPosition, new Vector2(200, 70));
        GUI.Label(rect, "TEST");
    }
}
```

I've just tested attaching that MonoBehaviour to a Cube GameObject and it works

Comment: Thank you for your help, but to me it still didn't work. I think it's because i have to use the GuiBarScript.cs i got from https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19972, so instead of a regular Rect, i use GUI.Drawtexture with a background too, like:GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(gameObjectsPosition.x, Screen.height - gameObjectsPosition.y, Background.width * ScaleSize, Background.height * ScaleSize), Background);